# Insert an image in MVC

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, hyperlink

I want to insert an image hyperlink to my MVC project.
I have a class (MyImg) that gives me an object (myImg) with the following properties:

[image]

How can I put this image hyperlink in my application?

All the answers I found are using an image URL, and not an actual image file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller with an action that returns FileContentResult. You'll then need to put that image into a MemoryStream and return it.. somewhat like below:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int ID)
{
    ClassYouHave hyperLink;
    // .. your code to load the data you've shown above
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        hyperLink.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return File(ms, "image/" + hyperLink.ImageType);
    }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here to view this picture!", "GetImage", "Ctrlr", new { id = 1 })
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'System.IO.File' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Why arre you copying the whole thing to memory, first? If the images are moderately sized, this could end up leaving the large object heap messy.

Comment: I need it because it is coming from some other system, and I need to present it in my application

Comment: No, I'm asking chemicalNova why his answer has you copying it  to a memory stream like that, when you could copy it more directly.

Comment: Free-hand typed. Apologies. If its over 85k yes it will mess with the LOH.